# Java Spring JPA insert into

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Please, help me execute a Postgres query in spring-data-jpa:

```
@Transactional
public interface JournalAdd extends CrudRepository<Journal, Long> {
        @Modifying
        @Query(value = "insert into journals (messageid, oldowner) values ('dgf', 'fgd')", nativeQuery = true)
        void updateJournalOldownerMessageid(Long id);
}
```

After execute no errors but in table added just one rows without values

o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [null]
o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - [null]

Postgres table journals:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "journals")
public class Journal implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "oldowner")
    private String oldowner;
    @Column(name = "messageid")
    private String messageid;
```

Comment: Table names in Postgresql are case-sensitive, so in the second query since you're using a native query set the table name as journal not Journal and message not Message.

Comment: Why don't you  manage this kind of business in your service layer instead of putting them in your repository?

Comment: tashkhisi , Journal this is a separate table. I added my postmaping. If Journal journal = new Journal(id,owner);  journalAdd.save(journal); then error "Inferred type 'S' for type parameter 'S' is not within its bound; should extend 'com.example.webapp.domain.Message'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `nativequery=true`, then you have to use pure postgres sql in `@Query`. You are using `JPQL` in `@Query` but telling JPA to execute is as a native query.

Change your `@Query` value with the query if have provided here. Your query should look like

```
@Modifying
@Query(value = "INSERT INTO journals (messageid, oldowner) select m.id, m.owner from message m where m.id = ?1", 
    nativeQuery = true)
void updateJournalOldowner(Long id);
```

Comment: Doesn't work  `@Query(value = "insert into journals (messageid, oldowner) values ('dgf', 'fgd')", nativeQuery = true)   void updateJournalOldownerMessageid(Long id);` 2020-10-26 10:13:28.522 TRACE 8396 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [null]
2020-10-26 10:13:28.522 TRACE 8396 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - [null]

Comment: In your query , there is no external parameter, so basicbinder should not print the logs you have shown. Are you sure you are executing the query you have commented ? Please set org.hibernate.SQL to debug and show me the query and binder logs.

Comment: `        Journal journal = new Journal();
        journal.setMessageid(id);
        journal.setNewowner(owner);
        journal.setDate(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
        journalAdd.save(journal);`